# Calling a function between quotation marks

Tags: python, function, api

I'm a beginner in programming and I'm currently trying to call a function between quotation marks.

Here, more precisely, I would like to replace the name in \"name\": \"name\", with 88. How would I be able to do that with all those quotation marks?

Thanks in advance for your help

```
import requests

url = "https://api.multiloginapp.com/v1/profile/create"

def descr():
    return 88

querystring = {"token":"xxxx"}

payload = "{\n\t\"generateZeroFingerprintsData\": true,\n    \"name\": \"name\",\n    \"OS\": \"MacOS\",\n    \"platform\": \"MacIntel\",\n    \"browserType\": \"mimic\",\n    \"proxyHost\": \"0.0.0.0\",\n    \"proxyPort\": 0,\n    \"proxyIpValidation\": false,\n    \"proxyType\": \"socks5\",\n    \"maskFonts\": true,\n    \"disablePlugins\": true,\n    \"disableWebrtcPlugin\": true,\n    \"disableFlashPlugin\": true,\n    \"canvasDefType\": \"noise\",\n    \"hardwareConcurrency\": 2,\n    \"langHdr\": \"en-US,en;q=0.8\",\n    \"timeZone\": \"US/Eastern\",\n    \"audio\": {\n        \"noise\": true\n    },\n    \"geolocation\": {\n        \"permitType\": \"block\"\n    },\n    \"mediaDevices\": {\n        \"audioInputs\": 1,\n        \"audioOutputs\": 1,\n        \"videoInputs\": 1\n    },\n    \"webgl\": {\n        \"noise\": true\n    },\n    \"webRtc\": {\n        \"type\": \"block\"\n    },\n    \"shared\": false\n\t},\n}"
headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
    'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
    'Postman-Token': "xxx
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: First, it looks like you're trying to generate some JSON. If so, why not just create a normal dict, which is easy, then call `json.dumps` on it? Or, even better, just pass the dict to `requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)`?

Comment: I recommend converting `payload` into a Python dictionary using the `json` built-in library and then changing the `name` key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do what you're directly asking how to do here is to use string formatting. For example, [using printf-style formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting),<sup>1</sup> instead of this:

```
payload = " … \"name\": \"name\" … "
```

… do this:

```
template = " … \"name\": \"%s\" … "
payload = template % (descr(),)
```

While we're at it, if you put the payload in single quotes, you wouldn't need to escape every `"`. Even better, if you put it in triple quotes, you wouldn't need to escape all the newlines. See [the tutorial section on Strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) for details:

```
template = """{
    \t"generateZeroFingerprintsData": true,
    \t"name": "%s",
    # …
}"""
```

But you can make things a whole lot easier by not doing any of this. You're trying to build a JSON text representing a dictionary. The easy way to do that is to [just create the dictionary and JSON-ify it](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html):

```
payloadobj = {
    "generateZeroFingerprintsData": True,
    "name": descr(),
    # …
}
payload = json.dumps(payloadobj)
```

Or, even better, let `requests` do it for you. [Instead of passing `data=` with a string, pass it `json=` with a dict, and it automatically JSON-ifies it, and also sets the `Content-Type` header for you](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests):

```
payload = {
    "generateZeroFingerprintsData": True,
    "name": name,
    # …
}
# …

response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)
```

(Also, notice that, instead of calling the generic `request` function and passing `POST`, which you really only want to do for [custom HTTP verbs that `requests` doesn't know about](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#custom-verbs), I used the simpler `post` function, [as shown in the quickstart docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request).)

---

<sub>1. In general, the newer braces-based formatting is simpler. Especially in 3.6+, where you can literally call a function inside quotes, just by wrapping it in braces inside an f-string, like `spam = f'eggs = {eggs()}'. But when the string you're trying to create is full of literal braces, but isn't full of literal percent characters, often that's an exception than the "in general".</sub>

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working perfectly. Any good reason to let requests do the job? I created a dictionary, and your better option seems pretty much identical